# Is there any reason not to farm Terramorphous on Normal mode?

Tags: borderlands-2

We just confirmed that Terramorphous is significantly harder on True Vault Hunter Mode, however his drops appeared to be pretty much identical. (For reference he has significantly less health and summons less tentacles). Roughly the same number of each rarity of item, still level 50 in both modes.

Aside from completing the mission for that playthrough, is there any benefit to killing Terra in TVHM? Some people say "TVHM gives better loot" as "common wisdom" that THVM is better, but TVHM really means "loot is higher level". So, considering gear level is the same, is there any reason not to fight the easier Normal Mode Terramorphous, other than for challenge?

Comment: We? What's that supposed to mean?

Comment: @Retrosaur Everyone. You weren't there? Nah I just meant I/we were playing coop.

Comment: @Retrosaur Ben, me and [Ian Pugsley](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/7816/ian-pugsley).

Comment: Late to the party again :C

Comment: @Retrosaur you play on Steam? I'm Sirtaptap if you do

Comment: @BenBrocka Indeed I do.  Not as much time, but still.  I play under my SE name :D.  Used to play some games with badp

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is absolutely no reason to, except for the challenge, farm Terramorphous on TVHM. All those getting better loot and all those theories are lies.

Terramorphous becomes easier on normal mode without the health and damage multipliers and it is recommended to farm him on normal mode.

The only reason to farm Terramorphous on TVHM is if you are looking for a real challenge.